# Short Story: Dogs own the country side, cull humans for food

Tags: story-identification

I'm trying to remember the name and author of a short story.  This is what I recall of the plot:

A transport/bus breaks down traveling between two cities in an implied post-apocalyptic setting.  It's revealed that packs of dogs control the countryside, they round up the passengers and break them into two groups - breeders and non-breeders.  They seem to do this by scent.  Non-breeders include the elderly and at least one gay character (one of the guards).  The dogs seem more intelligent than normal, it's not revealed why.  The breeders are then allowed to be rescued, while non-breeders are taken by the dogs - presumably as food.

There's an implication that this is a standard arrangement, that the dogs basically let humans continue to exist because we serve as an occasional food source.

Comment: When did you read the story? Was it in a book, magazine, anthology, or something else? Was it in English?

Comment: @phantom42: English, and I *think* it was an anthology.  My memory of the plot is a lot better than anything else around it.

Comment: Do you have any memory of the name, cover or editor of the anthology, or subject/authors of any of the other stories in it? ETA: you ninja-edited. obviously not all applicable if it wasn't an anthology.

Comment: I know this story I believe I read it in a post-apocalyptic anthology.  For an added detail it wasnt a guard it was a rescue agent sent from one of the cities that was gay and forced out of the rescue vehicle by the dogs.

Comment: @phantom42: I thought it might have been LE Modesitt Jr, but I took a look at his bibliography before posting and none of the titles looked correct.  I'm not sure on anything else you asked, unfortunately.

Comment: No worries. Just trying to suggest things that some people forget to mention, but can be very helpful to id a work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*[Fit for a Dog](http://www.baenebooks.com/10.1125/Baen/0743436075/0743436075__21.htm)* by Howard L. Myers.  It can be found in *[The Creatures of Man](http://www.baenebooks.com/p-90-the-creatures-of-man.aspx)*.  It is part of the [Baen Free Library](http://www.baenebooks.com/c-1-free-library.aspx).

Most of the details line up.  However, a character at the end *does* reveal how the dogs got to be that way.

> Their ancestors were left out in the smog while humans built and lived in domed cities.

Comment: That was it, thank you.

Comment: That was a really fun read! Thanks @DanSmolinske and thanks Leif for finding this :)